# Display toast in fragment getActivity() vs mActivity reference

Tags: android, android-context

Is calling the method getActivity() once in my fragment and saving the reference in mActivity better than calling getActivity() every time I want to show a toast message?

```
Toast.makeText(mActivity, text, duration).show();
```

vs.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, duration).show();
```

Comment: Both are same. No problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getActivity()` should be preferred for 2 reasons:
**1) Memory leak prevention**
Having a variable `mActivity` lying around opens up opportunities for memory leak e.g. mistakenly set the variable as **static**, makes it easy and convenient to reference the activity in some running anonymous `AysncTask`

**2) Correct nature of fragment-activity relationship**
Fragments can be attached or detached at many point of times. Therefore, getting a reference of the activity hosting the current fragment should be on a **on-demand basis**. Having a `mActivity` variable means you need to set and unset it correctly.

Take note that what `Toast` requires here is a `Context` object so it's not necessarily the activity that is required here. An application context object would also suffice

Comment: I agree with this answer, not with other.

Comment: I have one confusion here, how "having some long running anonymous AysncTask holding such reference" will not be a case while using 'getActivity()'?

Comment: one can abuse `getActvity()` the same way in AsyncTask. It's just the matter of mentality: mActivity = "hey I have the context, why not just use it" vs. `getActivity() = "hey I have request for it, oh wait, maybe I should not do it at all due to memory leak etc." @PankajKumar

Comment: @ericn :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Fragment wise both are same

***First one***

Activity **mActivity** = getActivity();

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

Toast.makeText(**mActivity**,"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**Second one**

use Directly like this

```
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a Context or Activity, no difference. but if you want to access some method or field inside the parent activity, you would better saving the reference in mActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the context just to show the `Toast` messages and getting references to Activity is difficult for you then you can use `getApplicationContext()` instead.